# Line between Sliding Tabs and Toolbar

Tags: android, slidingmenu

How to remove this line :

[image]

I tried to remove elevation:

```
<the.example.com.slidingtab.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

but I want shadow under sliding tabs.

Comment: post your codes and xmls

Comment: How to change xml that I post in order to see shadow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elevation is defined for Android 5.0 API level 21 LOLLIPOP.
I do not know what is your purpose, but for my purposes
I would target pre-21 devices and have a view with that shadow drawn on it (if nothing else helps, `<FrameLayout...>` can draw its children one on top of another).

For example, *horiz_line.xml*

```
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="2dip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    />
```

used from a `<LinearLayout ...>` as

```
<include layout="@layout/horiz_line"/>
```

draws a simple horizontal line. If you need a shadow, you could use a 9-patch image with a dark shadow drawn on transparent background.